# App de Flutter no se conecta a internet en release

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo una app que tiene que conectarse a internet para enviar y recibir información a través de unas APIs. Pero esto solo funciona en DEBUG, ya que en RELEASE parece no tener conexión a internet. **Recalco que tengo los permisos establecidos en  /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

Aquí pongo el AndroidManifest que tengo actualmente:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app_puntos">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
   <application
        android:label="app_puntos"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

    </application>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Como información adicional, decir que la conexión a la API es a través de una URL con HTTPS y que hay tanto envio como recepción de información. No sé si esto último influirá en algo realmente, pero toda información que de es poca, ya que no se como es posible que aún teniendo los permisos la app siga sin conectarse en release.

Comment: prueba si desde ese dispositivo tienes acceso a esa URL, desde tu navegador, quizás nunca llega la petición

Comment: Si, se tiene acceso a la URL. Lo que he estado viendo también es que la app funciona de manera extraña en release, hay funcionalidades que funcionan a veces si y a veces no, así que puede ser que haya algun paquete externo dando problemas o algo así.

Comment: Cuál es la API que estás usando @xXNukemKS ? Estas usando el widget expanded ?